# SignalR not fired when I am inserting a new row into database table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, sqldependency

Control page

```
public JsonResult Get()
{
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CustomerConnection"].ConnectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT TRN as 'Number of paid'
  ,CONCAT(Products.PRODUCT_NAME COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, 
  (CONCAT(' - ' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS, 
      KITCHEN_ORDER.RECEIPE_FOOD COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS)))as'Product name'
  ,CATEGORY
  ,KITCHEN_ORDER.[QUANTITY] as 'Quantity'
  ,ISNULL(KITCHEN_ORDER.RECEIPE_FOOD,'norecipe') as 'RECEIPE_FOOD'
  ,KITCHEN_ORDER.THE_RECIPIENT
  ,ISNULL(KITCHEN_ORDER.RECEIPE_FOOD,'pending') as 'Kitchen status'
  ,[ID_USER] as 'SALE MAN'
  FROM KITCHEN_ORDER
  INNER JOIN Products ON products.PRODUCT_ID = KITCHEN_ORDER.PRODUCTS_ID
  GROUP BY TRN, PRODUCT_NAME, RECEIPE_FOOD, CATEGORY, KITCHEN_ORDER.QUANTITY, THE_RECIPIENT, Status, ID_USER", connection))
            {
                // Make sure the command object does not already have
                // a notification object associated with it.
                command.Notification = null;

                SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                var listCus = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>()
                        .Select(x => new
                        {
                            Number_of_paid = (long)x["Number of paid"],
                            Product_name = (string)x["Product name"],
                            CATEGORY = x["CATEGORY"] != DBNull.Value ? (string)x["CATEGORY"] : "",
                            Quantity = (int)x["Quantity"],
                            RECEIPE_FOOD = (string)x["RECEIPE_FOOD"],
                            THE_RECIPIENT = (string)x["THE_RECIPIENT"],
                            Kitchen_status = (string)x["Kitchen status"],
                            SALE_MAN = (string)x["SALE MAN"]
                        }).ToList();

                return Json(new { listCus = listCus }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            }
        }
}

private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    CusHub.Show();
}
```

_layout page

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        // Proxy created on the fly
        var cus = $.connection.cusHub;

        // Declare a function on the job hub so the server can invoke it
        cus.client.displayCustomer = function () {
            getData();
        };

        // Start the connection
        $.connection.hub.start();
        getData();
    });

    function getData()
    {
        var $tbl = $('#tblInfo');
        $.ajax({
            url: $("#Get").val(),
            type: 'GET',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                $tbl.empty();

                $.each(data.listCus, function (i, model) {
                    $tbl.append
                    (
                        '<tr>' +
                        '<td>' + model.Number_of_paid + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + model.Product_name + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + model.CATEGORY + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + model.Quantity + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + model.RECEIPE_FOOD + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + model.THE_RECIPIENT + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + model.Kitchen_status + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + model.SALE_MAN + '</td>' +
                        '<tr>'
                    );
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Startup class:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

What can I do to solve this problem? SignalR is not firing any inserted data from database table.

Also my database connection is true also I can review data in web view but the SignalR cannot fire data.

Hub page

```
public static void Show()
{
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<CusHub>();
        context.Clients.All.displayCustomer();
}
```

View page

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number_of_paid</th>
            <th>Product_name</th>
            <th>CATEGORY</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>RECEIPE_FOOD</th>
            <th>THE_RECIPIENT</th>
            <th>Kitchen_status</th>
            <th>SALE_MAN</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody id="tblInfo">
        
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you configure endpoint ? I have hub named ChatHub. I have to add below code into Startup.cs under Configure(). Try it out. I was trying similar thing but with asp.net core mvc project.

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");                    
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chathub");               
        });
```